# Pandas reading too much data

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, memory-management, file-descriptor

I'm trying to open a file format using python, to this file I have chosen to use pandas (for speed and usability).

(I will attach full code below)
The code snippet to read the file is:

```
    with open( filename, "rb") as fd:
        hdr={}
        while True:
            pos = fd.tell()
            line = fd.readline().split()

            if line[0] == "SPACE":
                break

            key=line[0]
            for value in line[1:]:
                hdr.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

With that I read the text file header. After the while loop  `pos` over there has the position where the first non header structure was found (marked by the `SPACE` text). The file will contain many space structures (that are just a bunch of numbers).

Then I do a small rewind `fd.seek(pos)` and start to read the data itself (the space)

```
        # Building the header
        self.header = {
                [...] 
                'nospaces'    : int(hdr['NOSPACES'][0]),
                'objects'     : hdr['OBJECT']
                }

        # Probably there is a best way to do this
        [...]
        self.nospaces = self.header['nospaces']
        self.objects  = self.header['objects']

        fd.seek(pos)
        self.space=[]

        # Im using range(1) for sake of test
        for i in range(1): #range(self.nospaces): 
            self.space.append(lambda:0)
            line = fd.readline().split()

            # In the first line of SPACE we find a line like this:
            # SPACE 29768 s1_0411_sa
            # Where 28768 is the number of text lines of this space data
            # s1_0411_sa is the space title/name

            self.space[i].lines = int(line[1])
            self.space[i].name = line[2]
            self.space[i].data = pd.read_csv(fd,
                delim_whitespace=True,
                header=None,
                names=self.objects,
                nrows=self.space[i].lines,   # Here I read the exact number of lines
                index_col=(0,1),
                dtype="float32")
```

But after that running a:

```
fd.tell()
fd.readline()
```

Didn't return me the next SPACE structure data (since I expect pandas to read EXACTLY the number of lines I have asked for it) instead tt has returned me this position: `1310868` and the next line is the middle of some random line long after the second space structure. Trying to understand why this number I got:

`(1310868-148)/2**16 = 20`.

I think that, pandas read buffer was getting bigger and bigger and passed through the next entry.

I don't want to read the file more than one time,one to find the space structures and other to map the structures to pandas dataframes.

My question is, how to make pandas stop and return my file descriptor right after it reads the 29768th space line. (the value on s1.space[0].lines).

If there is no way to tell that to pandas, how can I achieve that without reading the file two times or memmapping it (I want to avoid data duplicity on memory) since these files can be huge?

Follows the full runnable code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

class space:
    def read(self, filename):
        with open( filename, "rb") as fd:
            hdr={}
            while True:
                pos = fd.tell()
                line = fd.readline().split()

                if line[0] == "SPACE":
                    break

                key=line[0]
                for value in line[1:]:
                    hdr.setdefault(key, []).append(value)


            # Building the header
            self.header = {
                    'x0'          : int(hdr['XAXIS'][0]),
                    'xinc'       : int(hdr['XAXIS'][1]),
                    'xmax'       : int(hdr['XAXIS'][2]),
                    'y0'          : int(hdr['YAXIS'][0]),
                    'yinc'       : int(hdr['YAXIS'][1]),
                    'ymax'       : int(hdr['YAXIS'][2]),
                    'nospaces'    : int(hdr['NOSPACES'][0]),
                    'objects'     : hdr['OBJECT']
                    }

            # Probably there is a best way to do this
            self.x0          = self.header['x0']
            self.xinc       = self.header['xinc']
            self.xmax       = self.header['xmax']
            self.y0          = self.header['y0']
            self.yinc       = self.header['yinc']
            self.ymax       = self.header['ymax']
            self.nospaces = self.header['nospaces']
            self.objects  = self.header['objects']

            print fd.tell()
            fd.seek(pos)
            self.space=[]
            for i in range(1): #range(self.nospaces):
                self.space.append(lambda:0)
                line = fd.readline().split()
                self.space[i].lines = int(line[1])
                self.space[i].name = line[2]
                self.space[i].data = pd.read_csv(fd,
                    delim_whitespace=True,
                    header=None,
                    names=self.objects,
                    nrows=self.space[i].lines,
                    index_col=(0,1),
                    dtype="float32")

            # This tell() goes far below the self.space[i].lines read.
            print fd.tell()
            print fd.readline()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s1=space()
    s1.read("data.txt")
```

The data file looks like this:

```
XAXIS 1525 2 1767
YAXIS 1525 2 2011
NOBJECTS 5
NOSPACES 2
OBJECT YAXIS
OBJECT XAXIS
OBJECT XCOORD
OBJECT YCOORD
OBJECT DEPTH
SPACE 29768 s1_0411_sa
1525 1525 125000.01 125000.01 5933.09
1525 1527 125164.05 125000.01 5870.35
[...] then more 29766 lines [...]
SPACE 29768 s2_0411_sa
1525 1525 125000.01 125000.01 19171.9
1525 1527 125164.05 125000.01 18967.5
1525 1529 125328.09 125000.01 18724.8
[...] more 29765 lines [...]
```

Comment: Your file isn't a CSV file.  You are better off preprocessing it to convert it into CSV rather than trying to pretend it is a CSV.  Then pandas will read it easily, and you can avoid all the fiddly stuff you're now wrestling with.

Comment: It's a solution that I'm trying to avoid. I of course could preprocess it using python itself and temporary files, but I don't want to go that way right now. Also I could memmap the file, split in memory and process with panda (but this will incur on data duplicity on memory). In fact I also have to process it in binary format, that I think that should be easier since  I know exaclty the ammount of data that I need to read. My plroblem here is that float numbers in text have variable size.